# Reference Implementation website throwing "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: paths" error

Tags: 2013, dxa

I am trying to set up Tridion Reference Implementation for first time. I am done with CMS part.

Now I am facing problem with Website setup as site is throwing below error.

> Value cannot be null. 
>   Parameter name: paths
>
> With Stack Trace goes like Stack Trace:  [ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: paths]
>   System.IO.Path.Combine(String[] paths) +6626904
>   Sdl.Web.Common.Mapping.SemanticMapping.Load(String applicationRoot)
>   +379    Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.SiteConfiguration.Refresh() +304    Sdl.Web.Site.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +343

I have set up the path value as "/" in cd_dynamic_conf and cd_link_conf files in my site/config.

Comment: I think path should be empty if the publication publishes to the root of your site. Also double check that you have items in your BINARY_VARIANTS and PAGE_CONTENTS tables (associated with the appropriate publication ID) in your broker DB - to make sure stuff is being published OK. This is an error if there are issues with serializing or reading the configuration - are there any files created in the /BinaryData folder of the site? Any other messages in the site.log file?

Comment: I can see data in broker DB against my publication Id. Even in the tables mentioned.

Comment: Are there folders and files created in the BinaryData folder in the root of the site and is there anything logged in site.log (check the location in /Log.config)?

Comment: Looks like the power shell script to setup the web application creates system folder outside BinaryData folder which is incorrect. System folder which has json configuration files, should be inside BinaryData folder. I manually copied the system folder at proper locatio which i got from log file and Yes...It was a success. Thanks a lot for the responses and pointer at the right areas.

Comment: The system folder is not created by the powershell script, its created by the web application when it starts (the JSON configuration files are simply serialized from the broker database to the filesystem), and always inside the BinaryData folder, so I think something else must be happening here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *believe* I had the same error while setting this up (not sure because I had a bunch of errors that I sorted through based on "gut feeling"), and it went away after I set up the cd_dynamic_conf to have the correct publication binding:

```
<Publication Id="8">
  <Host Domain="stri-v1" Port="81" Protocol="http" Path="" />
  <Host Domain="localhost" Port="81" Protocol="http" Path="" />
</Publication>
```

You mention you

> set up the path value as "/" in cd_dynamic_conf

Did you set a host name too? If you have multiple host names you can add it multiple times as in my example above.

**EDIT** Will may have a better guess than me on his comment. Can you share the storage conf for both your deployer and your webapp?

Comment: Yes, i have set the host name as as per my site domain.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common error, I'm just copying over my answer on this [other thread](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/tridion-reference-implementation-couple-of-installation-niggles), but the answer also applies here

You **don't have to** setup  the path to  "/"  on cd_dynamic or cd_link

I have seen it happening due to multiple issues, but the root cause is that the Web Application cannot reach the resources

The following issues will cause that same error:

- **sqljdbc4.jar** is not on the **lib** folder of the web application
- The database information is not correct on **cd_storage_conf.xml**
- **"Publish HTML Design"** page is not published or not correctly published
- The **application identity user** is does not have **permissions** to write the serialized files on the application folder
- Publication id or host domain not correct on cd_dynamic_conf

Comment: Apparently, i have tried all the options mentioned above but None seems to be working.

Comment: Is the BinaryData created on your web application folder? I would also check that the HTML Design and configuration pages are properly published to the Broker Database

Comment: Looks like the power shell script to setup the web application creates system folder outside BinaryData folder which is incorrect. System folder which has json configuration files, should be inside BinaryData folder. I manually copied the system folder at proper locatio which i got from log file and Yes...It was a success.